# Reinstale Cypress : Error al iniciar Cypress "npm run cypress open"

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm, cache, cypress

Al momento de ejecutar cypress se genera un error, al parecer no encuentra la instalación en la carpeta cache.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error sale cuando ya se intenta correr cypress con el comando "npm run cypress open" solo que en la captura esta indicado como "npm run test" debido a que "test= cypress open" en package.json

Ya intente varias soluciones que encontré y no funcionan, intente desinstalar e instalar node, borrar las carpetas de cache, crear el proyecto en mi carpeta admin, reinstalar cypress, se queda bloqueado cuando escribo "npm install cypress --force", no se que pueda pasar.

Version Node: 18.18.0
Version npm: 10.1.0
Version Cypress: 13.2.0